Sending a raw JSON body with Guzzle that contains an array
I am using PHP Guzzle to formulate a request to a 3rd party API tracking service.
I am able to successfully make API calls via a collection I have created using Postman, but I'm having difficulty forumating the JSON body in my PHP application.
The JSON body I am using in Postman is as follows:
{
    "trackingInfo": [
        {
            "trackingNumberInfo": {
                "trackingNumber": "1234"
            }
        }
    ]
}

This is set as JSON raw. As can be seen above, the keyvalue for "trackingInfo" is an array. In my PHP if I use json_encode it converts the array to an plain key/value pair and the api complains that the format is wrong.
I can get the API to accept my request with the following, but it is missing data:
$body = [      
     'includeDetailedScans' => 'true',
     'trackingInfo' => array_values([
          'trackingNumberInfo' => [
               'trackingNumber' => '775928562030'
          ]
     ])     
];

It seems to remove trackingNumberInfo:
'{"includeDetailedScans":"true","trackingInfo":[{"trackingNumber":"775928562030"}]}'

How can I retain the array in the body's raw json?
